# browser not parsing unicode urls correctly

Tags: php, url, unicode

Xampp(php(5.6.30, apache)
Windows

In the project I'm working there are urls using other languages. Mod rewriting is set and working correctly. The error is random, couple of urls are working properly and some of them are not. For example

```
<a id="article" href="/384/sadhna/dush-mahavidya/%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5-%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE">तारा महाविद्या साधना के अनुभव और खतरा</a>
```

In this url I'm straight away getting "Object not found!" page. When I started deleting characters in the browser's url bar and as soon as I reached

```
तारा-महाविद्या-साधना-के-अ
```

The post is getting loaded correctly.
Like wise there is another url which is getting parsed correctly.For example

```
<a id="article" href="/384/sadhna/dush-mahavidya/%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5-%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE">तारा महाविद्या साधना के अनुभव और खतरा</a>
```

I have no clue why it's happening. May be it's related to other language. Urls in plain english is giving no problems.

Comment: what are the rewite rules looking for `तारा` ... or `%E0%A4%A4%E0%` ...

Comment: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>